# Is there any way to check whenever a canvas is completed or not?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm encountering a problem and I don't know how to solve it nor why it acts this way, so i'm looking for some help

I am currently working on a little application which :
1 - builds *.png together on a single canvas
2 - Apply some styles, colors

The current application was running "perfectly" : the final canvas was containing the full built image with the correct assets and we could see the result.

Today, I've decided to extract the base64 from the canvas to render an actual image. The problem is that that base64 extracted at the time t is not the same as the one which is contained by the canvas tag itself. As a result, the final rendering is not the same (some parts of the drawing are erased in the image meanwhile the final canvas is perfectly fine).

Here is the code which manages the drawing :

```
ctx.save();
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
//images.forEach(function(child, index, array) {
//    ctx.drawImage(picture, child.anchor.x, child.anchor.y, child.width, child.height);
//});
ctx.restore();
console.log(ctx.canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
```

If I try to extract  the base64 from the canvas at the very end with the Google Chrome Console and store it as the source of the destination image, it works fine too. Here is my question : is there any event that is fired when a canvas is fully ready to go ? Do I do it wrong by trying to extract the base64 after ctx.restore() ?

Thanks a lot for your help,

Friendly yours (and sorry for my horrible english)

EDIT 1 : I'm using a function that allows me to do some pre-rendering, that's why there is only the drawImage in the code above since pre-rendering is already done.

Comment: _"extract the base64 from the canvas at the very end with the Google Chrome Console"_ by extract do you mean copy from the dev console? If so are you getting the full string, the console may truncate the string so you may not be getting the full base64 string

Comment: Hey Patrick, thanks for your comment ! Actually when I print the base64 canvas I got a string with a length of 39650 char. while the string coming for the toDataURL() above is only 30766 characters long

Comment: question 1 : "is there any event that is fired when a canvas is fully ready to go" The canvas is fully ready to go as soon as you called `document.createElement('canvas')`, or as soon as it has been parsed by the browser. Wrong question I guess. question 2 : "Do I do it wrong by trying to extract the base64 after ctx.restore() ?" :  Kind of yes. `ctx.save()`will stack the full properties set on the context (current matrix, fillStyles, clipping area etc.), `ctx.restore()` will pop the last stacked state and set it back to the context. These are heavy operations and absolutely not needed here.

Comment: But none of these questions will solve your issue. @PatrickEvans may have a good one here.

Comment: Canvas rendering functions are blocking, that means you can not do anything with the canvas until the rendering is complete. As I know of no reason for toDataURL to drop any pixels you must not be rendering the full content to the canvas you are getting the URL from.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your comments ! I would like to apologize first for the horrible question which was really poor enounced...

Thanks to the Blindman67 I did find where was the problem. What I did not say earlier (because I thought that wasn't part of the problem) is that my program is also "replacing" colors by other colors. Because of this, it has to handle some more Image.load() callbacks to print the differents images with their final colors. It semt that one ore more load() function were not totally fullfied, resulting in an incomplete frame. I manage to change the export so that each callback manage to come to its end before trying to export the final image.

Thanks a lot everyone for your help :)